# Dividing a String in multiple parts

Tags: java, string, split, substring

I'm making some school assignments and I stumbled upon a problem.

I have to divide the same String in 3 parts in order to get an output that looks like this: XXX-XXXXXXX-XX

I thought about using the Substring so I could easily split the String up but when I use it more then once in my String.format it always returns an error.

This is what my class looks like

```
public class BankAccount {
private String account;

public BankAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s - %s - %s", account.substring(0, 3), account.substring(3 - 10), account.substring(10 - 12));
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `account.substring(3 - 10)`, not good. Are you looking for `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` ?

Comment: Yes, isn't this any good?

Comment: Your return String is `account.substring(3 - 10), and (10 - 12));`   It should be `account.substring(3, 10), and (10, 12));`

Comment: You might want read the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) : _"IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object."_.

Comment: Ugh, darn I didn't notice that I was using "-" signs. And my IDE didn't mention any errors, for what is the "-" tag used then?

Comment: Because `substring(int i)` exists and `int` are signed. You were just calling `substring (-7)`, hence the exception.

Answer (score 4):

`account.substring(3 - 10)`

should be

`account.substring(3, 10)`

Same goes for `account.substring(10 - 12)`

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste mistake ;)